# How to Find $(24315) ◦ (14532)$ (Permutation composition)

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations

> How to Find $(24315) ◦ (14532)$

Can someone show me the algorithm how to do Permutation composition?

thanks

Comment: Authors vary in whether the composition of permutations proceeds left to right or right to left.

Comment: This depends on whether composition for you has been defined as reading it from right-to-left or from left-to-right.  Assuming it was from right to left, you can watch each element individually.  $1$ first gets mapped to $4$ from the permutation on the right, which then subsequently gets mapped to $3$ from the permutation on the left, so the overall result is that $1$ gets mapped to $3$.  Similarly $2$ gets mapped to $1$ followed by being mapped to $5$, so $2$ gets mapped to $5$ in the overall result.  Continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from right to left, following where the permutation that is the composition sends each element, 
$$
2\mapsto 1\mapsto 5\\
5\mapsto 3\mapsto 1\\
4\mapsto 5\mapsto 2\\
1\mapsto 4\mapsto 3\\
3\mapsto 2\mapsto 4
$$
So let's encode this in a cycle, 
$$
(25134)
$$

Comment: so for example if  I want to find the opposite $(14532)◦(24315)$ the answer $(13425)$?

Comment: that's right, yes.

Comment: thanks a lot ..